# python selenium how to deal with absence of an element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So Im trying to translate all the reviews on tripadvisor to save comments(non-translated, original) and translated comments (from portuguese to english).

So the scraper first selects portuguese comments to be displayed , then as usual it converts them into english one by one and saves the translated comments in com_, whereas the expanded non-translated comments in expanded_comments.

The problem now is that for comments which are already in english , there isnt any "Google Translate" widget inside them. But if there isnt any then also I want to atleast save these comments in as English itself. But Im unable to handle the absence of element.

Basically `save_comments(driver)` function is where its happening.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
com_=[]
expanded_comments=[]
date_=[]
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\shalini\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def expand_reviews(driver):
    # TRYING TO EXPAND REVIEWS (& CLOSE A POPUP)    
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("moreLink").click()
    except:
        print "err"
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click()
    except:
        print "err2"
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("moreLink").click()
    except:
        print "err3"


def save_comments(driver):
    # SELECTING ALL GOOGLE-TRANSLATOR links
    gt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".googleTranslation>.link")

    # NOW PRINTING TRANSLATED COMMENTS
    for i in gt:

        try:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",i)

            #com=driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_overlay").text
            com= driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class = 'ui_overlay ui_modal ']//div[@class='entry']")
            com_.append(com.text)
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_close_x").click().perform()
            time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    #AS PER user : BREAKS_SOFTWARE
    if gt.size()==0:
        print "ERR"

# ITERATING THROIGH ALL 200 tripadvisor webpages and saving comments & translated comments             
for i in range(56,58):
    page=i*10
    url="https://www.tripadvisor.com/Airline_Review-d8729164-Reviews-Cheap-Flights-or"+str(page)+"-TAP-Portugal#REVIEWS"
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    if i==0:
        # SELECTING PORTUGUESE COMMENTS ONLY # Run for one time then iterate over pages
        try:
            langselction = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.sprite-date_picker-triangle")))
            langselction.click()
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='languageList']//li[normalize-space(.)='Englsih first']").click()
            time.sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            print e

    save_comments(driver)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (gt.size() == 0): 
    insert code here to extract the english comments
```

Comment: Ive edited my code to show mixed reviews. it traverses starting from page 56 , which has english & non-english comments. But if you run the code english gets skipped

Comment: I don't see any edit in save_comments() that does anything if gt.size() == 0.  So anything that doesn't have that translate button will get skipped.  You need to add the code to handle this condition.

Comment: Where shall I put gt.size()==0 ? Also how can I know the numeric position of that element for which gt.size()==0 ?

Comment: Um, you would put it after the "for" loop inside save_comments().  that's where you are trying to save the comments, right?

Comment: you don't want it WITHIN the for loop, you want it AFTER the for loop.

Comment: Its not working.Can you pls try it at your end before posting here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125712/discussion-between-breaks-software-and-shalini).